# mirc how to get a bot send subscriptions to user

Tags: tcl, mirc

Im currently looking Trying to get ideas on how to Create a .mrc script for users that can subscribe to Tv shows. I'm running xdcc's so once they add new release of a show to the channel, for example: `Newly Added  New.Amsterdam.2018.S01E09.1080p.WEB.H264.METCON`,  the subscribed user would get a message or perhaps even the file automatically to be sent to them, by `./msg bot send nick #<show>. (New.Amsterdam.2018.S01E09.1080p.WEB.H264.METCON)`. Any ideas help thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, please read [the how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it is right now, your question shows no research effort nor show whether you have anything at all so no one can guess what exactly do you need help with. It might be that you need a tutorial on how to write scripts for mIRC, it's unclear. Asking for tutorials by the way is off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm not sure that I've formatted your question correctly, so please review and correct any errors, and it would really help if you showed us what code you've written so far.

Comment: Is this question still relevant ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an old format but still available to be used in irc. You might want to have a bot like a XDCC bot.

You can here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/xdccbrowser/

For the official XDCC, I still cant trigger any.

Hope this helps you.